# How can i use stuff function for multiple columns in SQL server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a requirement for concatenating two values of two rows having same Id's and averaging for other column. Here is the sample table I have:

[image]

Now my requirement is I need to concatenate the `Response` column, concatenate `Response Rating` column and average the `Rating Avg` column  if it has same `ParticipantId, UseriD, QuestionId and ConductedById`.

Here is the target data what I wanted:

[image]

Here `Response` column and `Response rating` column is concatenated with respective rows and `Rating Avg` column is taken the average. I have done one column concatenation previously using `stuff` function. Can this be achieved using stuff function?

Comment: Any time your turning multiple rows into delimited strings, you're probably trying to do display logic in a database!

Comment: Did you use "for xml path" when using stuff? Yes, that's possible for multiple columns too, but can be quite CPU intensive

Comment: Yes i used "For xml Path".Can you help me with the query.I have very few records so performance doesn't matter

Answer (score 8):

You can do the following. Just group by those columns and make 2 subselects for concatenated columns:

```
select UserID, 
       ConductedByID, 
       QuestionID, 

       (SELECT STUFF((SELECT ';' + Response
                      FROM TableName tn2 WHERE tn1.UserID = tn2.UserID and 
                                     tn1.ConductedByID = tn2.ConductedByID and
                                     tn1.QuestionID = tn2.QuestionID and 
                                     tn1.ParticipantID = tn2.ParticipantID
            FOR XML PATH('')) ,1,1,'')) as Response,

       (SELECT STUFF((SELECT ';' + cast(Rating as varchar)
                      FROM TableName tn2 WHERE tn1.UserID = tn2.UserID and 
                                     tn1.ConductedByID = tn2.ConductedByID and
                                     tn1.QuestionID = tn2.QuestionID and 
                                     tn1.ParticipantID = tn2.ParticipantID
            FOR XML PATH('')) ,1,1,'')) as [Response Rating],

       AVG(case when Rating = 'n/a' then 0 else cast(Rating as int) end) as [Rating Avg], 
       ParticipantID
from TableName tn1
group by UserID, ConductedByID, QuestionID, ParticipantID
```

Comment: Thanks Giorgi, worked perfect .I have another question .Is it possible to do conditional average on 'Rating Avg' column? I have some values with N/A in 'Rating Avg'. So average is not possible .Is there a way i can make average N/A when doing on both  N/A values and Numeric value when doing  combination of  N/A and numeric values and average when doing on both numeric values ?

Comment: What do you mean by N/A? Nulls?

Comment: No ,value is N/A (Not applicable).

Answer (score -1):

This works perfectly

```
STUFF( 
( 
   SELECT DISTINCT ',' + val_name 
          FROM   t_t43_value_set 
             INNER JOIN     t_t43_factory 
             ON             val_id = fac_country 
             INNER JOIN     t_t43_delivery delivery 
             ON   pvs_part_version_id = del_part_version_id 
             AND  pvs_supplier_id = del_supplier_id 
             AND  del_factory_id = fac_factory_id FOR xml path('')),1,1,'') AS 'Country'
```